LASER beam dispersion pattern
I see so far in all textbooks that LASER with a circular aperture are considered to diverge as Gaussian beam.
However is it really the case in the reality?
Isn’t the beam rather diverging as an Airy disc (at far distance like a few dozens or hundreds of kilometers) since the aperture is circular and the Gaussian beam is only a very good approximation?
I tried to found scientific papers on the topic with photos or instrumental evidence but failed to found anything conclusive.
Thanks

You might add context for what you're talking about in particular. Usually, lasers are studied for close-range purposes on the order of a few meters or kilometers at most, and only recently have they been implemented as communications systems and weapons at much longer ranges. It's possible the textbooks are just out of date.

According to Wikipedia, "A circular laser beam with uniform intensity across the circle (a flat-top beam) focused by a lens will form an Airy disk pattern at the focus." However real lasers don't necessarily uniformly illuminate their output apertures.

That said, a perfect 0th-order Gaussian beam can only form if the laser output aperture has infinite diameter, so the 0th-order Gaussian beam is also only an approximation to the actual beam shape.

@controlgroup I was thinking about LASER ranging application like the Moon LASER ranging.

@ThePhoton Thanks

Most lasers are designed to produce a close to a Gaussian beam as possible. They often do a pretty good job.
A Gaussian beam does not have a sharp edge. It fades away as you get farther from the axis, but theoretically is never gone. The beam diameter is defined as the diameter where the intensity is $1/e^2$ of the central maximum.
Lasers pass through an aperture, which clips the beam. This does have an effect on the beam. But if the aperture is large enough, only the faint edges of the beam is clipped, and the effect is small enough to ignore. The industry standard is to make the aperture diameter $1.5$ times the beam diameter. The intensity at the edge has dropped to $1$% of the central maximum at this diameter. This is considered good enough. Large diameter lenses are expensive and have larger aberrations, so larger than this is not used.
A good place to read about Gaussian beams and many other aspects of optics is the RP Photonics Encyclopedia. For example, see the articles on Gaussian Beams and Diffraction-limited Beams

You get an Airy disk when a beam with a uniform profile is focused to a spot.
A focusing lens turns Gaussian beam with a large aperture and small divergence angle into a converging Gaussian beam with a much steeper convergence angle and small beam waist. The focal spot has a Gaussian profile.
